# Can't remove \r and \n in textbox c#

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I using a textbox in c# and using a key press event that press enter and perform a button click action when the window is focus on that textbox

I notice that when the first time i perform "enter" and the event goes well.
When i go back to the previous page and i perform again same thing. i saw that the textbox have \r and \n even i already reset the textbox like

```
  textbox.Text = "";
  //OR
  textbox.Clear();
```

But somehow when i debug the \r and \n still exist in the textbox.

Did i do any wrong or any way to prevent such case happen?

Comment: textbox.Clear() should do the job - are you doing any other processing? If immediately after textbox.Clear() you check the content in the debugger, is the \r\n still there?

Comment: "go back to the previous page"...can you provide more information on what you are doing here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `e.handled = true` in your textbox keypress event, this will stop the text being added to the textbox in the firstplace. Just taking a guess, but can you put a breakpoint on `textbox.Clear();` I think the textbox may be empty at the point you are calling clear, and updating afterwards? Perhaps move the clear to the KeyUp event instead?

Comment: Great to hear, user2422414. If you have time could you please mark this as the accepted answer? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a bit more code in your question but I believe what is happening is that you have your .Clear() set in the `Form_Load` which only gets executed once, then when you go back to to the Form the second time it is already created (in memory) and all that happens is that you show it again. Use the debugger to make sure your .Clear() is in the right place and always called.

It may fit your case to do your Clear() action on the [Form Show](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Shown += Form1_Shown;
}

private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    textbox1.Clear();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Go back to the previous page" ?  Please also update your question with more code on what you are calling in what events. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

maybe try:

```
textbox.Text.Replace("\r", "");
textbox.Text.Replace("\n", "");
```

I was just suggesting another approach. Since Windows 10, the new line sequence has been treated with a weirdly non canonical approach. You can prove that by opening some .txt files in firefox and then in notepad. Sometimes there'll be a significant difference in line break locations. I've dealt with this somewhat recently, and my approach was exactly what I proposed: delete all `\r` charaters and `\n` charaters (don't treat them as a sequence) and then replace them with whatever you need.

Comment: Code only, but besides that OP has already tried to use `.Clear()` method without success.

Comment: yes, I was just suggesting another approach. Since Windows 10, the new line sequence has been treated with a weirdly non canonical approach. You can prove that by opening some .txt files in firefox and then in notepad. Sometimes there'll be a significant difference in line break locations. I've dealt with this somewhat recently, and my approach was exactly what I proposed: delete all \r charaters and \n charaters (don't treat them as a sequence) and then replace them with whatever you need.